# Indy 10 Http Server sample

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-7, indy

I need a simple code sample for Indy 10 Http Server When request (post) simply displays it
Is there an Indy 9 sample for this?
Thanks

Comment: so what is it? Indy 10 or Indy 9?

Comment: You can look it at ExtPascal sources

Answer (score 22):

1. Start a new VCL Forms project
2. Drop a TidHTTPServer component onto the Form
3. Double-click the form to create an *OnCreate()* event and activate the server

   IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
4. Back on the form, select the HTTP Server component, and create an *OnCommandGet* event

In this *OnCommandGet* event (which is called within a child thread whenever a GET/POST occurs), handle the request, by populating the response..

```
AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html><head><title>My First Response</title></head>' + 
  '<body>Command: ' + ARequestInfo.Command +
  '<br />Host: ' + ARequestInfo.Host +
  '<br />URI: ' + ARequestInfo.URI +
  '<br />UserAgent: ' + ARequestInfo.UserAgent +
  '</body></html>';
```

Depending on your Delphi version, you may also have to add *IdContext* to your *Uses* clause

Run your demo app and then launch a browser to http://localhost and you should get a response.  (Unless you have something else listening on Port 80 in which case your demo app will generate an exception)

Comment: Unfortunately, this response is about Windows exe, and not about Windows service as was asked.

Comment: Please re-read the post.  Where does it talk about Windows Service?

Answer (score 8):

The [Indy 9 samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20180808210125/http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/index.EN.aspx) are still available on the IndyProject site and include an HTTPServer demo project.  The [Indy 10 Demo Playground](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118061155/http://www.atozed.com/indy/Demos/10/index.en.aspx) does as well.

In IdHTTPServer, Get and Post commands are essentially treated the same and handled in the CommandGet event.

Comment: Just a note that links are now expired

Comment: Thanks! That's really nice of you